# XSL Elements missing

Tags: xml, xslt

Basically this is my XML with some historic data:

```
<events>
    <entry day="1" year="1901" month="1">
        <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
        <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
        <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
        <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
    </entry>
    <entry day="1" year="1902" month="1">
        <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
        <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
        <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
        <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
    </entry>
</events>
```

With the following XSL and some additional data coming via job ticket one corresponding entry should be selected:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ereignisse><xsl:call-template name="ereignisse"/></ereignisse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ereignisse">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//events/entry[
    (number(@year) = 1901) and 
    (number(@month) = 1) and 
    (number(@day) = 1)]">
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

So the output now is plain text. But it should look like:

```
<ereignisse>
  <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
  <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
  <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
  <event>Blablabla blablabla</event>
</ereignisse>
```

I tried several ways but without success. Hope you can help me...

Comment: That's not enough context for us to determine what is causing the problem. What is `$events`? Where are calling your named template from? A minimal but complete example that reproduces the issue would be ideal.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I edited the posting, hope that helps...

Comment: Your output now would not be plaintext but rather plaintext wrapped by a `ereignisse` element.  If you're not seeing the `ereignisse` element, perhaps you're viewing your output in a web browser?  Look at it via a text or XML editor instead.   See @michael.hor257k's answer for a better approach anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are applying templates to `entry` - but you have no template matching `entry`. In such case, the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) are invoked, and the effect is that text nodes are copied through.

To achieve the desired output, you could dispense with most of your code and do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/events">
    <ereignisse>
        <xsl:copy-of select="entry[@year=1901 and @month=1 and @day=1]/event"/>
    </ereignisse>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```